# Nginx keeps bad redirect for firefox

Tags: firefox, nginx, https, configuration

i am trying to solve problem. I want to redirect all urls starting with *www to non-www version* of site. In chrome and opera, it works well.

But when i go to **firefox** and open http://www.example.com it starts downloading page (mime-type octet/stream), on https://www the connection is not reliable. In other browsers it set mime-type text/html.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name www.example.com;
        return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        root /var/www/domain/www;
        index index.php;
        server_name example.com;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
        root /var/www/domain/www;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php;

        server_name example.com;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args ;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Comment: Do you set the HSTS headers? Because you will need to reset Firefox to lose that particular history. I do not know why the MIME type is strange, but you only redirect www to non-www for `http` connections - and HSTS will force Firefox to ignore your `http` servers and go straight to the `https` server.

Comment: Clearing all cache in firefox helped, thanks